# How do I send spring csrf token from Postman rest client?

Tags: spring, rest, header, csrf, postman

I have **csrf protection** in spring framework. So in each request I send csrf token in header from ajax call, which is perfectly working.

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
```

**In ajax**

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token),
                xhr.setRequestHeader("username", "xxxx1"),
                xhr.setRequestHeader("password", "password")
            }
```

I haven't any idea to **generate csrf token and include in header section of Postman Rest Client** ? Would you please help me to send csrf token from Postman Rest Client? 
[image]

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The Easiest way to do this consistently so you don't have to get the token each time:

1. Create a new environment so environment variables can be stored

[image]

2. Create a login method with a test to store the XSRF cookie in an environment variable, in the test tab post this code

   ```
   //Replace XSFR-TOKEN with your cookie name
   var xsrfCookie = postman.getResponseCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
   postman.setEnvironmentVariable("xsrf-token", xsrfCookie.value);
   ```

**EDIT**
For anyone using the 5.5.2 postman or later you will also have to decode the cookie, and they have also provided alternative ways to obtain cookies as  @Sacapuces points out

```
pm.environment.set("xsrf-token", decodeURIComponent(pm.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")))
```

Now you will have an environment variable with xsrf-token in it.

3. Save your login method
4. Create the new post you want to create and in the headers add your XSRF-Token-Header Key, and the environment variable in handle bars to access it{{}}

[image]

5. Now before running your new request make sure you run your login, it will store the environment variable, and then when you run the actually request it will automatically append it.

Comment: Proposed an edit to change the cookie name to: postman.getResponseCookie("XSFR-TOKEN"). That works for on a JHipster project based on SpringBoot 1.4.2.RELEASE. If that brokes other scenarios please let know in the comments or propose an edit.

Comment: And to find out the postman version you are using , Click the "wrench" --> Choose "Settings" from the list --> Select "About" tab. You will see postman version.

Comment: @johnny5 Could you provide screenshots for where to put 

var xsrfCookie = postman.getResponseCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");  and 
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("xsrf-token", xsrfCookie.value);. Please help.

Comment: @user I’m not at my computer right now. But in the first screenshot you can see a tab called tests. Click that tab and place the code in there

Comment: Got it. But Should it be X-CSRF-TOKEN or XSRF-TOKEN? When I open the Chrome console for my webapp, I see the key name as X-CSRF-TOKEN.

Comment: It depends on what your using, if your using spring 1.4.2 or later this should work otherwise you’ll need to read the documentation

Comment: How is the Get and the subsequent post related? Can I get in one machine and post in another ?

Comment: @BlueClouds the login method runs and set a variable in postman.  The get method appends the variable stored in postman as the xsrf toke

Comment: @johnny5 where do you have to paste the code in step 2? I tried clicking on the 'Test' tab as you suggested but there is no such option. I can edit an environment and define a key value pair over there.

Comment: Just asking out of blue Did you mean to add code in postman tab under "cookies"? I'm lost but ill try figure out.

Answer (score 11):

I am able to send REST with csrf token by following the steps below:

1. The CSRF token generated automatically by spring security when you logged in. It will be shown at the response header.
2. The CSRF token can be used on subsequent request by setting X-CSRF-TOKEN with CSRF token on header.

Comment: It worked for me, but a little different, I got the CSRF Token from the cookies in the cookies tab, and used it on the header of the POST request using the header name X-XSRF-TOKEN

Comment: I copied the X-CSRF-TOKEN from the headers sent back by Spring Security and simply added `&_csrf=<token>` to my post URL.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly you need to install PostMan Interceptor and activate it to have access to the browsers cookies.

1. You have to fetch the CSRF Token by making a GET Request:
   Header: "XSRF-TOKEN" and Value: "Fetch"
2. You should see the Token in the cookie tab and can copy it (Notice: You can configure spring how the cookie should be named. Maybe your cookie has another name than "XSRF-TOKEN". Attention: You have the remove this blank char in the token from the newline)
3. Now make your POST Request and set the header to: Header: "X-XSRF-TOKEN" and Value: "Your copied Token without blanks"

Answer (score 3):

For me works variant with adding X-CSRF-TOKEN to headers.
[image]

Comment: How to get csrf token ?

Answer (score 2):

Please put **X-CSRF-Token** as key and **FETCH** as the value in the GET request header and you will receive the token in the response header

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to configure environment variables etc. here is the quickest solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49249850/3705478

Answer (score 0):

I've used csrfTokenRepository() to allow spring security to generate csrf token

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    // your code
    } 
}
```

After adding these lines of code, use GET request to generate csrf token. I've used postman and I got token in the response cookies section. Copy the token and use it in POST call.

Official documentation link :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/csrf.html