# Can we get the CSRF tokens from a website using chrome console

Tags: security, testing, csrf, web-development-server

As the CSRF tokens are stored in the frontend of a website, is it possible to access them using some script or are they human readable. Also, can a malicious script from an attacker access the CSRF token from a browser of a legitimate user and send a new request exactly what an attacker wants. If yes, how can we secure it?

working on implementing CSRF token in my system.

Answer (score 0):

> As the CSRF tokens are stored in the frontend of a website, is it possible to access them using some script or are they human readable.

Yes, definitely.  Human readable or not is irrelevant... the only relevant part is that the correct data can be sent back to the server when forms are submitted.  Usually, that's just some literal value, but it can also be computed client-side.  Either way, it's possible to get client-side.

> Also, can a malicious script from an attacker access the CSRF token from a browser of a legitimate user and send a new request exactly what an attacker wants.

Yes, of course.  Who's to say what a "legitimate" user is, anyway?  Certainly code cannot determine this.  You have to build a system around what you, the human, thinks is legitimate.

> If yes, how can we secure it?

CSRF attacks have nothing to do with verifying whether or not the request comes from a human user or a script.  That's not the problem CSRF tokens are trying to solve.

The only thing CSRF tokens are for is preventing requests from other origins (or rather, origins that couldn't obtain a token) from submitting data on the behalf of a user on the legitimate origin.  This used to be a problem where cookies were relied upon for authentication, yet cookies would be submitted when a form from a different origin was posted.  Frankly, if you build out your API in a way such that you're not relying on cookies for auth, and if you use the right methods (like `PUT` and `POST`) for things that change data, then you don't have a problem to worry about.

Comment: okay thanks. a legitimate user can be an authorised user who has access to the website and is logged in. so can we see/access the CSRF token value from the ReactJs script from chrome or any other browser console. The only concern is that can a malicious script from an attacker access the CSRF tokens and send a new request from the authorised user's origin or webbrowser itself.

Comment: @AyushJain There is nothing you can do to prevent a request from an agent acting on the user's behalf, whether malicious or not.  At best, you can use heuristic methods like reCAPTCHA.

Comment: yes. but can we access any variable from a live website using a script? if yes then we also can access the CSRF token as well

Comment: @AyushJain Yes, you can access practically anything from the site with a script.  That's why I'm telling you that the CSRF token does not solve for this scenario.  That's not what it's for.

Comment: thanks alot. so can you please tell me how can i differentiate between a request sent from an attacker from different browser or even from the same as user who has all the credentials, CSRF token and is on same IP as the user is.

Comment: @AyushJain You can't.  It's impossible.

Comment: this blog shows that it can be accessed. can you please check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384321/how-to-fetch-and-reuse-the-csrf-token-using-postman-rest-client

Comment: @AyushJain Yes, it *can* be accessed.  It's *impossible* to protect against such attacks.  It's impossible for you to deterministically know the difference between a user asking their browser to do something and a script impersonating that user asking their browser to do something.  (Or even, something pretending to be a browser.)