# Invalid CSRF Token via Postman

Tags: node.js, express, csrf, mean-stack, postman

I am using the csrf protection in my MEAN-Stack Application with the csurf node.js module.

As long as I send POST requests from my Angular frontend to the web service, everything works fine. But if I try to make a POST request via postman, I'll always face:

> "ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token"

According to the first answer from [How do I send spring csrf token from Postman rest client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182701/how-do-i-send-spring-csrf-token-from-postman-rest-client) i get the Token out of the cookie from the login request and set it to every post request.
Get requests are working fine.

I configured it as follows:

```
app.use(csrf({cookie: {path: '/', httpOnly: true}}));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.csrfToken();
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
    res.locals.csrfToken = token;
    next();
});
```

Best regards,

Tobias

Comment: The problem should be, that the token changes with every request in postman.