# how to make laravel api request with postman

Tags: laravel-5

I was testing delete,put request from **Postman** to my local laravel project
**Get** request is working fine with **postman**

but when i use delete or any other request to my site with postman it gives me page expired error i didn't tried with post request only delete, put

I want to return some json data or some string with delete, store, update

with **Form Spoofing** everything is working fine

this is my routes.web.php
`Route::resource("dept_settings",'DepartmentController');`

this is how i created Controller
`php artisan make:controller DepartmentController --resource`

Answer (score 0):

Are there any logs that give more information ?

I think you are experiencing a `TokenMismatchException`. 
Consider moving your routes to `routes.api.php`, or take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35925413/6242681 for more information about adding CSRF / XSRF to postman.