# How to return Bean class Object as JSON in Rest Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here my controller is like,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/restCallRequest", headers = 
 "Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Void> callRequest(@RequestBody CallRequestData  
 requestData, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

    if (requestData.getIvrName().isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    System.err.println("IVER Name is "+requestData.getIvrName()+" lsit "+requestData.getContactList().get(0));

   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/restCallRequest").buildAndExpand(requestData).toUri());
  return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED); 
}
```

And my Bean Class is,

```
@Entity
public class CallRequestData {
private int id;   //Auto incremented
private String ivrName;
private List<String> contactList;
public CallRequestData(int id, String ivrName, List<String> contactList) {
    this.id = id;
    this.ivrName = ivrName;
    this.contactList = contactList;
}
//setters And Getters
```

Here my POSTMAN send JSON

```
{
    "ivr_name":"welcome",
    "contactList":[
           "9040210495",
           "958045830"
    ]
}
```

And Also i want Response as like Request,
    {
        "ivr_name":"welcome",
        "contactList":[
               "9040210495",
               "958045830"
        ]
    }

> How can i solve it. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.flexjson</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexjson</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Write one method in controller.

```
public String toJson(User bean) { 
  return new JSONSerializer().transform(new DateTransformer("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),java.util.Date.class).serialize(bean);
    }
```

and pass your bean object to this method.

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(toJson(bean),headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

change return type to string in method signature `public ResponseEntity<String> callRequest`

**NOTE: For Spring boot you can use @RestController annotation which will auto convert objects to json.**

Comment: `@RestController ` would set the transform for the whole class, if some of your methods don't want that feature, you could use `@ResponseBody` on methods which need that.

Comment: exactly..that is the reason i have given both options here..thanks.

Comment: Can you change my all controller here ? here i am getting Error on Return. Thanks for comment. i am new in Spring. @Alien

Comment: Sure just give me some time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to reply

Comment: Thanks @Alien for gives me a sample. it's a very helpful. thanks once again.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Add Jackson dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and add

```
@RequestMapping(value="/endpoint",produces="application/json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

`produces="application/json"` to the request mapping. \

Now whatever, bean is defined after `@ResponseBody` will get returned as a json object to client. There is no need to parse it as json externally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you make all this option.
Is so easy.

If your controller is annotated with @RestController, you have just to return the object like this:

```
@RequestMapping..................................)
 public ResponseEntity<CallRequestData> callRequest(@RequestBody CallRequestData 
 requestData, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
```

......... code here ......

```
  return new ResponseEntity<>(requestData, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

}

Set the return type on the response entity and then return just return a new instance of ResponseEntity it like this.

I suggest you avoid multiple RETURN, assign a variable to the ResponseEntity and return just once at the end of the method

Comment: But it gives Error, `HTTP Status 404 – Not Found                                     
 Status Report Message /restCallRequest Description.The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.` In POSTMAN

Comment: How did you set the @RequestMapping  Also in my example there also a CallReqestData as input.. show me your method

Comment: fine it work but one another error `HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden  Type Status Report. Message: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.Description. The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.` and thanks to reply.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/restCallRequest", headers = "Accept=application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<CallRequestData> callRequest(@RequestBody CallRequestData  requestData, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
  if (requestData.getIvrName().isEmpty()) {
   return new ResponseEntity<CallRequestData>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
  }
  System.err.println("IVER Name is "+requestData.getIvrName()+" lsit "+requestData.getContactList().get(0));
 
      return new ResponseEntity<>(requestData, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }`

Comment: in the security config add http.csrf().disable(); or you have to pass also the token in this way: <input type=hidden name="${_csrf.parameterName} value="${_csrf.token} >

Comment: But Dear this is a rest App Here not <form> tag. Here i used here to run POSTMAN.

Comment: that is an example, if you use postman in the request you have to add 2 var: crsf token name and  crsf token. or you can disable this security with http.csrf().disable(); if you don't need it now. Basically spring generate a token name and a token value, everytime you POST you have to serve  also this token.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182701/how-do-i-send-spring-csrf-token-from-postman-rest-client