# Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again. - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I create a route `Route::post('/ddos/store','DdosController@store');`

I also have a controller

```
public function store()
{

    dd("HERE");

    $ddos                = new Ddos;
    $ddos->ip            = $ip;
    $ddos->details       = $details;
    $ddoss->save();

    return $ddos;

}
```

I kept getting - when making a TEST post via postman

[image]

I suppose to see the text "HERE" from my controller.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf.

Comment: Can I allow localhost? and my production VM IP to make the call ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the host or IP. Read the link.

Comment: I know that. They did that for security reasons. But my goals to open up one route for my VM to make a POST to.

Comment: Is there a way to disabled CSRF token protection on a specific route ?

Comment: The second section of the link is titled "Excluding URIs".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a middleware executed before `dd` line executed. It's called [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token). You can exclude it by adding this line in the `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`.

```
    protected $except = [
        '/ddos/store',
    ];
```

If you insist to keep sending csrf token with postman, you can create tests case and save it in environment variable (which i suggest). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182701/how-do-i-send-spring-csrf-token-from-postman-rest-client) might help you.

Answer (score 4):

Postman is not sending a CSRF token in the request and your route is under the `web` routes group which applies the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware

Either move your route to an `api` group or add it as an exception

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'ddos/store'
    ];
}
```

Comment: What Laravel version is your suggestion? Mine is 5.8. It looks like this ![](https://i.imgur.com/DfAXbge.png)

Comment: You can always override the properties of the BaseVerifier

Comment: @kyo A base Laravel 5.8 install's VerifyCsrfToken looks like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/5.8/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php Yours came from somewhere else - perhaps the app was an older version and not updated?

Comment: On the contrary, it's the latest 6.x