# REST APIs POST/PUT/DELETE methods works in Postman only with CSRF off (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, csrf

I am trying to send `JSON` via Postman to my aplication, but always getting error:

```
HTTP Status 405 ? Method Not Allowed
Message: Request method 'POST' not supported
Description: The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.
```

With `csrf().disable()` in Spring Security config everything works fine.

I have simple `rest` controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class CustomerRESTController {

    @PostMapping("/customers")
    public @ResponseBody Customer createNewCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        //...
        return customer;
    }
}
```

`JSON` in Postman body (content type is set to `JSON`, Method `POST`: http://localhost:8080/api/customers/):

```
{
    "firstName": "Testname",
    "lastName": "Testlastname",
    "email": "test@something.com"
}
```

Is there way how to use `POST/PUT/DELETE` requests in Postman with `csrf` enabled ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182701/how-do-i-send-spring-csrf-token-from-postman-rest-client